# SQL sum field and select a column (with condition) and sum another column

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, sum, conditional-statements

I have a select statement:

```
  SELECT ID, A, B, C, D
    FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID, A, B, C, D
  HAVING D >= '14/06/2013'
     AND D <= '17/06/2013'
```

show this:

```
ID   |    A   |    B    |   C   |     D   
--------------------------------------------
11   |  1370  |    0    |  0    |  14/06/2013
11   |  1370  |   100   |  0    |  15/06/2013
11   |  1470  |   400   |  0    |  16/06/2013
11   |  1870  |    0    | 300   |  17/06/2013
```

I Want the result is:

```
ID   | min of D|  Sum(B) |  Sum(C) |  max of D|   MIN(D)
11   |  1370   |   500   |   300   |   1870   |  14/06/2013
```

How do I do that on SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way (assuming SQL Server 2005+):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY D DESC),
            RN2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY D)
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE D >= '20130614'
    AND D <= '20130617'
)
SELECT  ID,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN2 = 1 THEN A END) [min of D],
        SUM(B) [Sum(B)],
        SUM(C) [Sum(C)],
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN1 = 1 THEN A END) [max of D],
        MIN(D) [Min(D)]
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID
```

Results:

```
╔════╦══════════╦════════╦════════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║ MIN OF D ║ SUM(B) ║ SUM(C) ║ MAX OF D ║  MIN(D)    ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════╬════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 11 ║     1370 ║    500 ║    300 ║     1870 ║ 2013-06-14 ║
╚════╩══════════╩════════╩════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

And [**here is an sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2fa4/4) with a demo of this.

Comment: Why bother with the CTE in this case?

Comment: @Goat_CO Mostly for convenience. Your answer is actually not correct, since op wants the value of `A` for the minimum value of `D`, and then the same for the maximum value of `D`, those two values are the same as the max and min for `A` in this case, but that is a coincidence. I'm using `ROW_NUMBER` for this and I find that CTEs are easier to understand than a derived table

Comment: That makes sense, the question didn't make that clear but it looks like you made the correct assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by a JOIN

```
SELECT  T.ID ,
        MAX(G.B) AS [SUM(B)],
        MAX(G.C) AS [SUM(C)],
        MAX(MINI)AS [MIN(D)] ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN T.D = G.MINI THEN T.A ELSE NULL END ) AS [MIN OF D],
        MAX(CASE WHEN T.D = G.MAXI THEN T.A ELSE NULL END ) AS [MAX OF D]
FROM    TEST T
JOIN    ( SELECT ID , SUM(B) B ,SUM(C) C ,MIN(D) AS MINI ,MAX(D) AS MAXI
          FROM  test 
          WHERE D >= '06/14/2013'
             AND D <= '06/17/2013'
          GROUP BY  ID ) G ON G.ID = T.ID
GROUP BY T.ID
```

SQL Fiddle demo [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc26d/1)